# how do I make a call Directly when open my contact

Tags: java, android, apk, call, contacts

the problem when I click on Button choose a contact and choose a contact not call the number, I want when choosing a Number phone call Directly

```
buttoncontact = findViewById(R.id.choosecontact);


public void choosecontact1 (View view){

     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

   intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT)


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String call = buttoncontact.getText().toString();


    if ((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER }, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String phone = cursor.getString(0);
```

// the Problem on that code

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.valueOf("tel:" + CONTENT_TYPE)));
```

// i want open phone contact and call directly

```
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.


                    return;

                }

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "CONTENT_TYPE"? Shouldn't it be the phone string you just get?

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
```

Comment: yes i put that and try many times but nothing work still work Like normal code

Answer (score 0):

1. Add permission in manifest file :
2. Make function of calling phone number

   private static final int CALL_REQUEST = 100;

   ```
    private void callPhoneNumber(){
           if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
           {
               if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ProfileActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, CALL_REQUEST);

                   return;
               }
           }

           Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
           callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9879879879" ));
           startActivity(callIntent);

       }
   ```
3. Above api level 23, need to ask runtime permission of call and if user allow it, it will go in below method :

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                          int[] grantResults)
   {
       if(requestCode == CALL_REQUEST)
       {
           if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
           {
               callPhoneNumber();
           }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   }

Comment: you can check now @BaselBeso

Comment: Okay that code work for Permission call yes but my problem is when i choose Button choosecontact1  when i click on any contact Number still Not want to call but your Permission code work good

Comment: you can replace "9879879879" with your contact number by click on button.